# Can't retrieve type information via Roslyn

Tags: c#, roslyn

I am attempting to retrieve the type of a class syntax node in Roslyn so I can get the enclosing namespace by following along with @slaks answer: [Roslyn : How to get the Namespace of a DeclarationSyntax with Roslyn C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29479200/roslyn-how-to-get-the-namespace-of-a-declarationsyntax-with-roslyn-c-sharp)

I have the following:

```
static async Task MainAsync(string[] args)
{
    string projectPath = @"C:\Projects\ertp\Ertp.Mobile.csproj";
    var msWorkspace = MSBuildWorkspace.Create();

    var project = msWorkspace.OpenProjectAsync(projectPath).Result;

    foreach (var document in project.Documents)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(project.Name + "\t\t\t" + document.Name);
        SemanticModel model = await document.GetSemanticModelAsync();
        var classes = document.GetSyntaxRootAsync().Result.DescendantNodes().OfType<ClassDeclarationSyntax>();
        foreach (var klass in classes)
        {
            var info = model.GetTypeInfo(klass);
            var isNull = info.Type == null; //TRUE
        }
    }
```

If I can't get the type I can't the namespace - any idea how I can retrieve the details I require?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For decelerators you need to call `model.GetDeclaredSymbol(node)` and then for the namespace, `ContainingNamespace`.

`model.GetTypeInfo(node).Type` will work for expression node.